# Facebook Realtime Updates Subscription Verification in Python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, amazon-ec2, flask, real-time-updates

I've been trying to set up a subscription for my app with the [Realtime Updates API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) but there have been some issues.  For starters, this is the error I keep getting:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#2200) callback verification failed: Operation timed out after 6000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received","type":"OAuthException","code":2200}}
```

I've followed the documentation appropriately and configured a Flask endpoint on an Amazon EC2 instance that handles HTTP GET and POST.  What happens is I hit and endpoint myself, manually, to invoke the subscription code.

```
curl -i -X GET http://public-ip-of-ec2:5000/subscribe
```

The above curl calls a script running in a flask application at the route of /subscribe on my ec2 instance.  To make the POST with the required query string parameters including our **access_token, object, fields, verify_token, and callback_url** I'm using the python HTTP library [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

```
VERIFY_TOKEN = 'my_verify_token'

@app.route('/subscribe')
def subscribe():
    global VERIFY_TOKEN
    FB_CLIENT_ID = 'my_app_id'
    # access_token is sent as a query string parameter
    APP_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'my_app_access_token'

    # object, fields, callback_url, and verify_token are sent as urllib.urlencode([('param','val')])
    CALLBACK_URL = 'http://my-public-ec2-ip:5000/'

    payload_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/subscriptions".format(FB_CLIENT_ID)
    payload = {"access_token": APP_ACCESS_TOKEN, "object": "user", "fields": "feed", "verify_token": VERIFY_TOKEN, "callback_url": CALLBACK_URL}   
    r = requests.post(payload_url, data=payload)
    return r.text


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def handle_requests():
    global VERIFY_TOKEN
    if request.method == 'GET':
        mode = request.args.get('hub.mode')
        challenge = request.args.get('hub.challenge')
        verification = request.args.get('hub.verify_token')

        # if we have our verification token back echo the challenge back to facebook
        if verification == VERIFY_TOKEN:
            return challenge

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # do some stuff with the updates
```

I'm confused as to why I'm getting 
     {"error":{"message":"(#2200) callback verification failed: Operation timed out after 6000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received","type":"OAuthException","code":2200}}

because when I fire up my flask application I can see a GET request from **173.252.110.113**, which is a Facebook IP address.  I have properly tested to make sure I'm echoing back the correct data by printing the challenge to my log for testing.  So the code IS returning the challenge which facebook requires to verify subscription and at that point the subscription SHOULD be successful, but the aforementioned error is what I'm getting.  Could it possibly just be a security issue I need to add a permission for in ec2 security groups or something??

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

ANSWER:

Facebook without forewarning sends multiple requests to the endpoint in question and with the Flask development server those requests have no way of being handled, therefore the timeout.  I fired up a gunicorn server with a few workers to test that theory and it proved to be true because I now have a successful subscription verification.  For anyone else having this issue with flask:

```
$ sudo pip install gunicorn
$ which gunicorn
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn


# fire up your endpoint with a few gunicorn workers to handle the load
# facebook tests our endpoint with (we will use 4 workers on port 5000)
# my_app is your_app_name.py without the .py part     

$ /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 4 -b my-local-ipv4-ip:5000 my_app:app
```

Answer (score 0):

"https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/subscriptions".format(FB_CLIENT_ID)

is for getting current subscriptions by GET method

to make new subscription you can try :

"https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/".format(FB_CLIENT_ID)

by POST method  --- import : is do not include **subscriptions**  at the end url